# Как узнать номер порта по которому подключился клиент к серверу

Tags: c++, сервер, visual-studio-2015, tcp, windows-8

Использую библиотеки Winsock2 и Ws2tcpip.
IDE - VS15
OS - Windows8

Comment: так номер порта по которому слушать определяет сервер - клиент незная порта не сможет подключиться ...

Comment: и не бывает случаев когда по разным портам возможно подключение к серверу?

Comment: бывают. но вы сами эти порты задаете.

Comment: Вот я пытаюсь так вывести  port_client = ntohs(client_addr.sin_port); 
Но порт другой выводится

Comment: Вы уверены, что правильно понимаете, как работают приложения с клиент-серверной архитектурой ? Но и это не главное, - где Ваш код ?

Comment: @isnullxbh Глупые у вас вопросы http://pastebin.com/u4fKWgTm

Comment: @helldrg, ну, судить Вам, конечно. Раз уж Вы с самого начала сомневаетесь в моей компетентности в этом вопросе, то не буду вдаваться в подробности, а просто предложу Вам освежить свои знания о TCP - почему он считается full-duplex, что называют "конечной точкой", а после этого запустить Ваш сервер, клиент telnet'a, в отдельной терминале набрать netstat -an - и, думаю, все станет на свои места )

Comment: Зачем запускать telnet и netstat? Конечные точки, я так понял это адреса сервера и клиента грубо говоря, а full - duplex  обозначает, что они имеют двунаправленную связь. Я просто понять не могу, почему нельзя просто вывести порт по которому подключился клиент к серверу.

Comment: @helldrg, да кто Вам сказал то что он не выводится ????? Зачем telnet, зачем netstat, затем чтобы Вы увидели, какой порт слушает Ваш сервер, какой порт используется в EP клиента, и увидели это все в выводе netstat'а, сравнили с тем, что выдает Вам сервер !

Comment: @helldrg, и, если вступили в диалог, будьте добры ставить метку @.

Comment: @isnullxbh порт выводится! Но какой то другой может клиента, может еще чего то, а нужен тот, по которому подключаешься к серверу. Я уже писал, что нашел такую функцию port_client = ntohs(client_addr.sin_port); ей какой то порт получаю. netstate там огромный список выводит, не прокрутить его, а в telnet что мне писать надо?

Comment: @isnullxbh про telnet и netstat я ничего не знаю

Comment: @helldrg, так, давайте так: Вам нужен порт, который Вы указываете на сервере, перед тем, как сделать bind (который же 666) или другой ?

Comment: @isnullxbh  да, а у меня другой порт выводит(

Comment: @helldrg, так хорошо, разобрались ) Укажите пожалуйста на кусок Вашего кода, который, по-Вашему, выдает не то, что Вы ожидали.

Comment: @isnullxbh я не знаю как это сделать, одно из предположений сделать так: port_client = ntohs(client_addr.sin_port);

Comment: @helldrg, допустим, и что, тот порт, который Вы используете в клиенте не совпадает с тем, что Вы получаете с помощью ```ntohs(client_addr.sin_port)``` ? Просто у меня все работало корректно. Скиньте и код клиента.

Comment: @isnullxbh код клиента http://pastebin.com/u5PZnJKp
 код сервера http://pastebin.com/zUw0C0Kz
Если вы через telent и netstat проверяете, напишите последовательность действий